# Can I disable Dashboard in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, preferences, dashboard

I'm wondering if there's a way to disable the dashboard in Mountain Lion.  I never use it and I think it's consuming processor and memory powers.

Comment: Look in Activity Monitor to see how much CPU and memory it uses, I expect that it will be negligible if you have added no widgets.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With macOS 10.10 Yosemite or later, you can go to
**System Preferences** → **Mission Control** and switch **Dashboard** to **Off**.

[image]

On any OS with Dashboard, you can disable it through Terminal with the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -boolean YES && killall Dock
```

It can be re-enabled with:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled && killall Dock
```

Comment: thanks!  I like the idea of the dashboard but the widgets available are absolutely terrible.

Comment: Is there a command to automate it in Yosemite?

Comment: @Allen Automate what exactly? `mcx-disabled` still works in Yosemite DP4

Comment: It does not work for me on 10.10 Beta. Actually some other defaults write commands does not work for me either.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Dashboard at all, free Apps are available to disable & enable (if you wish to revert) it including:

- [Bye Bye Dashboard](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21111/bye-bye-dashboard)
- [‘Disable & Enable Dashboard’ Utility](http://www.natal.be/index.php/?p=6)

**EDIT**

Alternatively see also this Youtube tutorial published on August 9th 2013 entitled ["Removing the Dashboard (MacMost Now 902)"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwF9oWTc80w#at=27)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just uncheck the 'Show Dashboard as a Space' checkbox in the Mission Control settings

Comment: This doesn't disable dashboard.

Comment: Just what I wanted, as I was always accidentally moving to the dashboard when switching spaces.

Answer (score 0):

No hacks/apps or terminals needed.

Before you start you can Launch Activity Monitor and filter by dashboard to see this work.

Remove all dashboard items and see that the dashboard process disappears.
Add them again and all is back to normal.
And then use Greg's answer to remove it from Spaces.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work because the LaunchDaemons are still active, and rebooting will only bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

#### To *permanently* disable Dashboard

1. open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
2. enter these commands, authenticate when prompted:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled -boolean YES; killall Dock
   sudo mkdir /System/Library/LaunchDaemons\ (disabled)
   sudo launchctl unload -w com.apple.dashboard.advisory.fetch.plist
   sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dashboard.advisory.fetch.plist \
           /System/Library/LaunchDaemons\ (disabled)/
   ```